# Is there a particular meaning of graffiti in The Smashing Pumpkins' music video for "Ava Adore"?

Tags: music-video

Not being much of a fan of The Smashing Pumpkins, I've only just today first seen the music video for their song *Ava Adore*. Immediately, a graffiti caught my attention. Here is the screenshot (it is around 3:42 mark in the video):

[image: Screenshot of "Ava Adore" music video]

Now, this might be just my imagination, but to me it says `СМРТ ЗА СМРТ`, which in several Slavic languages means *death for death*.

I couldn't find any references online pertaining to the writing, and search for the phrase only yielded results for the song of the same name (*Smrt za smrt*) by Slovenian industrial band Laibach.

Is there a particular reason for using this phrase? Is it possible that it somehow relates to the lyrics and the themes of the song? Or have I just discovered an Easter egg almost twenty years after the video's been made?

Comment: I expect it was something the set designers saw in a photo resource taken during the breakup of Yugoslavia. That section of the set is clearly the interior of a building in a conflict zone. Given the time period and the language, probably Serbia. Given the wide variety of sets, it seems doubtful there is any particularly deep meaning in this one, but I am only speculating so I can't consider this an answer. I mean, the immediately preceding one looks Roman. John Beard designed the set.

Comment: @yorik Thanks, I really appreciate your opinion. It didn't cross my mind that the set might be based upon a photo, but now that you've mentioned it, it does make sense. And this certainly cranks the set designer's level of attention to details up a notch.